# Sending through data from multiple dropdown lists with same select name in php

Tags: php

I'm here with a maybe bad formulated question, but I hope it's good enough for you to understand.

I'm creating this cash register for a local bar. Untill now it all works fine, I can let them pay the full bill etc, but if for example 1 person would leave early and want to pay for their own drinks it goes wrong.
Let's say the table has a total of 5 cola's, 3 ice teas etc, but the person only wants to pay for 1 cola and 1 ice tea -- HOW do I do this? I managed to make it look like this : http://gyazo.com/b5e4136d781677578a0da1d07c8b6d84 as with the dropdowns, you can select 1-5 for the cola and 1-3 for the ice tea.

How can I make it so that if I select 1 cola and 1 ice tea, I can send the data from both these through to the next page? The problem I'm having is because the select giving these option values, is always having the same name...

My code for hopefully a better view on what I'm trying to say.

```
  <?php
                           $vorigepag = $_POST['tafelid'];
                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM bestellingen where TafelID=".$vorigepag;
                    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));

        $totaal = 0;
         while( $rij = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) )
         {
             $id = $rij['ID'];
             $TafelID = $rij['TafelID'];
             $ProductID = $rij['ProductID'];
             $aantal = $rij['Aantal'];

                 $sql1 = "SELECT naam, prijs FROM producten where ID=".$ProductID."";
                $query1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));

                while( $rij = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1) )
         {
             $Product = $rij['naam'];
             $Prijs = $rij['prijs'];

            $Prijs = $aantal * $Prijs;
            $totaal += $Prijs;  

        echo '  <tr>    <form method="post" action="rekeningsplits.php">    

                <td><select name="hoeveel">';
                $extraaantal =0; 
                while ($extraaantal <= $aantal){
                echo '<option value="'.$extraaantal.'">'.$extraaantal.'</option>
                '; $extraaantal = $extraaantal +1;}
                echo '</td></select><td>'.$Product.'</td>
```

As you can see, my select name is "hoeveel", but now I don't know how to get multiple values from the select having the same name...

Comment: Do you have a field for Quantity?

Comment: @S.Pols if you would be able to explain or show me an example on how, I'd happily implement that...
MarcoMura the amount of drinks being read from the db = $aantal, the selected amount would become $extraaantal in the option list

Comment: for the select you can use -> multiple="yes" and with that you will read the data with an array for that field on php page. as php.net teach -> http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your select statement as an Array. Change this rule:

```
<td><select name="hoeveel">';
```

Into:

```
<td><select name="hoeveel['.$rij['ID'].']">';
```

Then after posting you can catch the multiple posted select values with something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['hoeveel'] as $productId => $hoeveel)
{
    echo "The product id ".$productId." is ".$hoeveel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfectly helped me :) Would vote up but need more rep points, now I at least have the data I need so I can work on my stuff :)

Comment: Good :)! Vote up is not needed. Just close the question by accepting the answer if it was usefull or delete the question. Good luck!